# Why do I get a "Variable used before being initialized" error on the line that I initialise the variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting this compiler error in an iOS project using Swift. If I create the following class:

```
class InitTest {

    let a: Int
    let b: Int
    let c: Int

    init () {
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4
        self.c = self.runCalculation()
    }

    func runCalculation () -> Int {
        return self.a * self.b
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error on the line `self.c = self.runCalculation()` saying "Variable 'self.c' used before being initialized".

At first I thought this was because the compiler could not verify that the `runCalculation()` method did not access `self.c`, but then I tried mixing the init method up a bit:

```
init () {
    self.a = 3
    self.c = self.runCalculation()
    self.b = 4
}
```

and this time the error is "Variable 'self.b' used before being initialized" (on the same `self.runCalculation()` line). This indicates that the compiler *is* capable of checking which properties the method accesses, and so as far as I can see should have no issue with the initial case.

Of course this is a trivial example and I could easily refactor to avoid calling the calculation method, but in a real project there could be several calculations each of which could be quite involved. I'd like to be able to separate out the logic to keep things readable.

Fortunately there's a simple workaround:

```
init () {
    self.a = 3
    self.b = 4

    self.c = 0
    self.c = self.runCalculation()
}
```

(or using a property initialiser `let c = 0`) but I'd like to understand why the compiler has a problem with the first example. Am I missing something or is it an unnecessary restriction?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Swift has this behaviour because of two phase initialisation. From Apple's Swift book:

> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first
>   phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class
>   that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property
>   has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given
>   the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the
>   new instance is considered ready for use.

Classes need some kind of default value before the first phase ends. Customising values is part of the second phase.

Objective-C didn't have this behaviour because it could always give `0` as default for primitives and `nil` for objects, but in Swift there is no mechanism to give such a default value.

Comment: When does the first phase end? I would have thought that `self.c = self.runCalculation()` is still in the first phase.

Comment: First phase ends after you give initial values to stored properties for root class in class hierarchy. So in this case it ends when you set `self.c = 0`.

Comment: If I use `self.c = self.a * self.b` instead of calling the method then there's no problem. What is it about calling a method that changes things?

Comment: @rankAmateur: A method could be overridden in a subclass (which assumes the superclass properties to be fully initialized).

Comment: @MartinR good point. Any comment on quote from manual `An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete`?

Comment: @Kirsteins Yes - that explains the method call not being allowed. I find it a bit strange that it allows access to `self.a * self.b` if you cannot read the values of any instance properties.

Comment: @MartinR yes that makes perfect sense

Comment: May turn function runCalculation() into property c’s lazy getter property  fix this?