# Swift: Call self method inside init

Tags: swift

I want to implement something like this:

```
class A {
    var a, b, c, d: Int

    init() {
        reset()
    }

    func reset() {
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = 3
        d = 4
    }

    func blablabla() { 
        ...
    }
}
```

which cannot get compiled, error message:

> Variable "self.a" used before being initialized

It doesn't make sense that I will have to copy the code from `reset()` into `init()`.

Is it a defect or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Very similar question here: [Why do I get a “Variable used before being initialized” error on the line that I initialise the variable in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038889/why-do-i-get-a-variable-used-before-being-initialized-error-on-the-line-that-i)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not a defect, simply `self` cannot be referenced in an initializer until all stored properties have been initialized, and a super class initializer has been invoked (if any).

In your case it seems legit to do the initializations in a method, and call that from the initializer, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Possible solutions:

- make the properties optional or implicitly unwrapped (discouraged, unless you really need them optionals)
- initialize the properties with fake values before calling `reset`:

  ```
  init() {
      self.a = 0
      self.b = 0
      self.c = 0
      self.d = 0

      reset()
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  var a = 0
  var b = 0
  var c = 0
  var d = 0

  init() {
      reset()
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Give a, b, c, and d default values, especially if you are going to change them right away.