# Swift: Create Class with NSTimer

Tags: swift, class, initialization

I want to create a DirectoryWatcher class that detects whether a directory has changed its first level content and then calls a delegate. This will also run in another thread.

Here is my code:

```
protocol DirectoryWatcherDelegate {
    func directoryDidChange(path: String)
}

class DirectoryWatcher {

    private(set) var path = ""
    private let timer: NSTimer
    private let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    private var previousContent: [String]
    let delegate: DirectoryWatcherDelegate?


    init(initPath: String) {
        path = initPath
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("checkDir"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func start() {
        previousContent = getContentAtPath()
        timer.fire()
    }

    func stop() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    private func checkDir() {
        if previousContent != getContentAtPath() {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if let delegate = self.delegate {
                    delegate.directoryDidChange(self.path)
                } else {
                    print("No delegate has been assigned")
                }

            })

        }
    }

    private func getContentAtPath() -> [String] {
        var content: [String]
        do {
            content = try fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path)
        } catch {
            content = []
        }
        return content
    }
}
```

My Problem ist in the `init` methode, where I initialize the `NSTimer`. Because this is the `init` methode I am not able to use self, bacause it is uninitialized.

How to fix this?

BTW: The error messages I am getting are:

> The variable self.timer used before initialized

and

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: Why are you saying you can't use `self`? Is the compiler complaining? Do you actually have an error message of some sort?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Sorry, I just added them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a "Variable used before being initialized" error on the line that I initialise the variable in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038889/why-do-i-get-a-variable-used-before-being-initialized-error-on-the-line-that-i)

Comment: Fixing the first error will resolve the second error.  First error is explained in that link.