# variable used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift

I m having a problem with this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
    var secondArrays :  SecondTableData

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        secondArrays = secondArrayData[indexPath.row]
    }
    destViewController.secondArray = secondArrays.secondTitle    
}
```

I m having an error in the line

```
destViewController.secondArray = secondArrays.secondTitle
```

> secondArrays used before being initialized

why am I getting that error? Please help, just a newbie with Swift. TIA

Comment: did u run it step by step, does it get inside your if{}?

Comment: if `if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` fails, then `secondArrays` would still be uninitialized. Therefor, the compiler is giving this warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a "Variable used before being initialized" error on the line that I initialise the variable in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038889/why-do-i-get-a-variable-used-before-being-initialized-error-on-the-line-that-i)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because of the way of initialising variables in Swift, In Swift Class each property need some default value before being used.

> Class initialisation in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first
>   phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class
>   that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property
>   has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given
>   the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the
>   new instance is considered ready for use.

Try changing your code as below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
  var secondArrays :  SecondTableData?

  if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    secondArrays = secondArrayData[indexPath.row]

    //Here you're making sure that the secondArrays would must have a value
    destViewController.secondArray = secondArrays.secondTitle
  }

}
```

Comment: because it may not get inside if{} where actual object is assigned to it, right?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have the error because `secondArrays` could be used without any initialization if your `if let` fails.

Try the following logic:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController
  guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

  destViewController.secondArray = secondArrayData[indexPath.row].secondTitle
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change the type of `secondArrays` to an implicitly unwrapped optional (`SecondTableData!`) and that should get rid of the build-time error. note if the the variable is not initialized and you try to access it, a runtime error will be thrown

also, if you change the variable to a `let` this method won't work.